# Scraping table into R

Tags: r

Trying to scrape data into R from table on website but having some trouble in finding the table.  The table seems to not have any distinguishable class or id as it is labeled as .  I have scraped data from many tables but have never encountered this type of situation.  Still a novice and have done some searches but nothing has worked as of yet.

I have tried the following R commands but they only produce a result with "" and no data scraped.  I had some results in assigning the article-template class but it is jumbled so I know that the data exists on the html_read. I am just not sure the proper way to program for this type of website.

Here is what I have so far in R:

```
library(xml2)
library(rvest)

website <- read_html("https://baseballsavant.mlb.com/daily_matchups")

dailymatchup <- website %>%
  html_nodes(xpath = '//*[@id="leaderboard"]') %>%
  html_text()
```

Essentially pulling the data from the table should allow a quick and organizable data frame.  This is the ultimate target I am seeking.

Comment: I think you would need `RSelenium` to scrape the table. Do you see table contents in `website` ?

Comment: Yeah, the table you see on that website seems to be pretty much pure JavaScript. ``read_html`` only works with pure html, you'll need something that behaves more like an actual browser and executes the JavaScript. As mentioned above, ``RSelenium`` might work for you.

Comment: Thank you both for pointing that out.  I will look into RSelenium and see if that works.